# Converting a Number to a Tuple and Memory Error

Tags: python

So I have to convert a given number n into a set of tuples using the definition of natural numbers. I figured out how to do that however if I input a large number such as 1000 it takes a long time and produces a memory error. How would I make this code run fast and not take too much memory?

```
output = [(),((),)]
def n_to_tuple(n):
    if n < 0:
        return None
    if n == 0:
        return output[0]
    if n == 1:
        return output[1]
    if n < len(output):
        return output[n]
    while n >= len(output):
        output.append(tuple(output))
    return tuple(output[n])
```

Comment: Runs fine when I try it.

Comment: `output.append(tuple(output))`?!? That's appending successive copies of `output` to itself, nesting more and more deeply. What's the goal here?

Comment: `2^1000` is a really big number.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Somewhat oddly, that is exactly the goal. In this approach to natural numbers, each natural number is defined to be the set of natural numbers below it, which leads to more and more nesting when you spell it out.

Comment: There's enough aliasing involved that the amount of memory used grows only quadratically, not exponentially. That doesn't make this efficient - it's horribly inefficient - but there shouldn't be a MemoryError for n as small as 1000.

Comment: Works for me too, and takes no time at all.  Are you running this on your phone or a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Good point about the aliasing, though something like `str(n_to_tuple(1000))` causes definite problems.

Comment: @JohnColeman: Ooh, yeah, and if you tried to run `n_to_tuple(1000)` *interactively*, Python would try to autoprint the result. *That* would cause a MemoryError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that this construct as "data", fits into the memory since when you do the union step, existing tuples are not copied/duplicated, only references are made to them.
As an intermediate step, here is a cut-back variant of your code:

```
output = [()]
def n_to_tuple(n):
    if n < 0:
        return None
    if n < len(output):
        return output[n]
    while n >= len(output):
        output.append(tuple(output))
    return tuple(output[n])
```

however as tuples are immutable, I had to modify them to lists, and after printing the original, scattered some appends (which would not work with tuples):

```
output = [[]]
def n_to_tuple(n):
    if n < 0:
        return None
    if n < len(output):
        return output[n]
    while n >= len(output):
        output.append(list(output))
    return list(output[n])

for i in range(5):
    print(n_to_tuple(i))

print()
output[0].append('x')

for i in range(5):
    print(n_to_tuple(i))

print()
output[1].append('y')

for i in range(5):
    print(n_to_tuple(i))
```

Produces

> ```
> []
> [[]]
> [[], [[]]]
> [[], [[]], [[], [[]]]]
> [[], [[]], [[], [[]]], [[], [[]], [[], [[]]]]]
>
> ['x']
> [['x']]
> [['x'], [['x']]]
> [['x'], [['x']], [['x'], [['x']]]]
> [['x'], [['x']], [['x'], [['x']]], [['x'], [['x']], [['x'], [['x']]]]]
>
> ['x']
> [['x'], 'y']
> [['x'], [['x'], 'y']]
> [['x'], [['x'], 'y'], [['x'], [['x'], 'y']]]
> [['x'], [['x'], 'y'], [['x'], [['x'], 'y']], [['x'], [['x'], 'y'], [['x'], [['x'], 'y']]]]
> ```

As you can see the x-s and y-s are suddenly everywhere, data is not copied/duplicated, but referred. That's how your large list of tuples fits into the memory, because those tuples are re-using each other and at the end there is an 1001-element list (which is nothing), with 1001 tuples inside, some of them are referring a lot of other tuples, but that's just an identifier in the memory. We are talking about less than a megabyte of storage this way.

Things radically change when you want to print the result, that's when you run out of memory. Actual output is prepended with the input and the length of itself here:

> ```
> 0: [2] ()
> 1: [5] ((),)
> 2:[11] ((), ((),))
> 3:[24] ((), ((),), ((), ((),)))
> 4:[50] ((), ((),), ((), ((),)), ((), ((),), ((), ((),))))
> 5:[102]
> 6:[206]
> ```

So length of the string duplicates in each step (and gets some extra increase, but let's ignore that part). That's what @Selcuk means when writing "*`2^1000` is a really big number*". For comparison: 1 gigabyte is `2^30` bytes.